# MultiValueDictKeyError. Exception Value: 'tipo'

Tags: jquery, django, filter, django-views

I am trying to send the value of a button to a search page by filters. This page is made up of several urls, each one to make a query with a type of filter. My view POST collects the value of the 'type' and sends it to the getType view, but when it receives it, it gets a MultiValueKeyError. How can I submit the type filter to the search page?

#### views.py

```
class Index(ListView):
    model = Coche, CocheBrand, CocheModel, CocheType, CocheDoors, CocheGearshift, Localidad
    context_object_name='coche_list'
    form_class = IndexSearch

    def get_queryset(self):#
        coches = Coche.objects.filter(reserved=False, sold=False).order_by('-precio')[:2]
        total_coches = Coche.objects.filter(reserved=False, sold=False).count()
        queryset = {'coches':coches,'total_coches':total_coches}
        return queryset
    def get_context_data(self):
        context = super(Index, self).get_context_data()
        context['marca'] = CocheBrand.objects.all()
        context['modelo'] = CocheModel.objects.all()
        context['tipos'] = CocheType.objects.all()
        return context

def CocheList(request): #LOAD SEARCH PAGE
    return render(request,'wallacar_app/cars.html',{} )

class CocheListing(ListAPIView):
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    serializer_class = CocheSerializers
    def get(self, request):
        if request.POST['tipo']:
            getType(request)
            return render(request, 'wallacar_app/cars.html')
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryList = Coche.objects.all()
        brand = self.request.query_params.get('brand',None)
        model_name = self.request.query_params.get('model_name',None)
        type_car = self.request.query_params.get('type_car',None)
      
        if brand:
            queryList = queryList.filter(brand = brand)
        if model_name:
            queryList = queryList.filter(model_name = model_name)
        if type_car :
            queryList = queryList.filter(type_car = type_car)


def getType(request):
    if request.POST['tipo'] and not request.method == 'GET':
        type_car = Coche.objects.filter(type_car=request.POST['tipo']).order_by('type_car').values_list('type_car').distinct()
        type_car = [i[0] for i in list(type_car)]
        data = {'type_car':type_car}
        return JsonResponse(data,status=200)
    #    return render(request, 'wallacar_app/cars.html', data)
    if request.method == "GET" and request.is_ajax() and not request.POST['tipo']:
        type_car = Coche.objects.exclude(type_car__isnull=True).exclude(type_car__exact='').order_by('type_car').values_list('type_car').distinct()
        type_car = [i[0] for i in list(type_car)]
        data = {'type_car':type_car}
        return JsonResponse(data,status=200)
```

#### index.html

```
{% block content %}
     

    <div class="site-section pt-0 pb-0 bg-light">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">

              <form action="wallacar_app/lista/tipo" method="POST" class="trip-form">
                {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="row align-items-center mb-4">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h3 class="m-0">TIPOS DE COCHES</h3>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">

                  <div class="form-group" style="width: 100%;">
                    <label for="tipos">Tipo</label><br>
            {% for tipo in tipos %}
                      <button name="type_car" value="{{ tipo.type_car }}" style="width: 25%;" id="{{ tipo.type_car }}" class="form-control px-3 btn-primary btn">{{ tipo.type_car }}</button>
            {% endfor %}
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  </form>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

#### Search.html

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="type_car">TIPO DE COCHE</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="type_car" 
                            url = "{%url 'wallacar_app:get_type' %}">
                            <option value='all' selected>TODOS LOS TIPOS</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

#### js load form in search.html

```
 getAPIData();

    getType();


    $('#type_car').on('change', function () {
        // get the api data of updated variety
        if(this.value)
            send_data['type_car'] = this.value;
        else
            if(this.value == "all")
                send_data['type_car'] = "";
            else
                send_data['type_car'] = this.value;
        getAPIData();
    });

function putTableData(result) {
    // creating table row for each result and

    // pushing to the html cntent of table body of listing table
    let row;
    if(result["results"].length > 0){
        $("#no_results").hide();
        $("#list_data").show();
        $("#listing").html("");
        $.each(result["results"], function (a, b) {
            if (b.reserved === true && b.sold === false){
            row = /* is a test */
                  '<li>'+
                    '<span>Tipo: </span>'+
                    '<span class="spec">'+ b.type_car+'</span>'+
                  '</li>'
function getAPIData() {
    let url = $('#list_data').attr("url")
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
        data: send_data,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#no_results h5").html("Cargando...");
        },
        success: function (result) {
            putTableData(result);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            $("#no_results h5").html("Algo no funciona....");
            $("#list_data").hide();
        }
    });
}
function getType() {
    // fill the options of provinces by making ajax call

    // obtain the url from the provinces select input attribute

    let url = $("#type_car").attr("url");
    // makes request to getProvince(request) method in views

    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
        data: {},
        success: function (result) {
            type_option = "<option value='all' selected>TODOS LOS TIPOS</option>";
            $.each(result["type_car"], function (a, b) {
                type_option += "<option>" + b + "</option>"
            });
            $("#type_car").html(type_option)
        },
        error: function(response){
            console.log(response)
        }
    });
}
```

#### /app/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from wallacar_app.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('lista/', CocheList),
    path('lista/tipo', tipoIndex),
    path("listado_coches/", CocheListing.as_view(), name = 'listing'),
    path("ajax/marca/", getBrand, name = 'get_brand'),
    path("ajax/model/", getModel, name = 'get_model'),
    path("ajax/location/", getLocation, name = 'get_location'),
    path("ajax/type/", getType, name = 'get_type'),
]
```

#### /urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from wallacar_app.views import Index, CocheDetalles, done

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',Index.as_view(template_name="wallacar_app/index.html"),name="index"),
    path("wallacar_app/",include(("wallacar_app.urls","wallacar_app"), namespace = "wallacar_app")),
    path('detalles/<str:pk>/',CocheDetalles.as_view(),name="detalles"),
    path('done/<str:pk>/', done, name="done")
]
```

Answer (score 0):

tipo is not the name of any form input's name. Please check your post form first. I have checked but did not find any form control with name "tipo"

Comment: Its true, i have type_car, not 'tipo', but i have the same problem if i change 'tipo' for 'type_car' in my view.